# Embed ASP.NET server code in JavaScript

Tags: asp.net, javascript, embed

I've embeded the following server side code within <script> tag.

```
<%  Dim dataTable As DataTable = cTab.getTabs(Session("UserID"))
    If (dataTable.Rows.Count > 0) Then
       For i As Int16 = 0 To dataTable.Rows.Count%>
       {
           contentEl: 'tab'+'<%dataTable.Rows(0)("TabID").ToString()%>', 
           title: '<%dataTable.Rows(0)("TabName").ToString()%>',
           closable: false,
           autoScroll: true
           },
        <% Next
    End If %>
```

But it is not returning the desired results due to syntax problems. How can I write it correctly?

Comment: could u please explain what do u want to do? and what syntax errors u are facing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've only given us a portion of the entire javascript, so we can't analyze what the surrounding script looks like in order to look for syntax issues.  The snippet you've given will just start with an opening curly brace, which is not valid just standing by itself.  What's preceeding it?

Besides that, if you want to output a string to the script, you need to do it using `Response.Write` or using the `<%= %>` shortcut.  So for one, you need to do:

```
   contentEl: 'tab'+'<%= dataTable.Rows(0)("TabID").ToString() %>', 
   title: '<%= dataTable.Rows(0)("TabName").ToString() %>',
```

(Notice the = signs).

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the surrounding code....

Looking at the loop each item is generated with a trailing comma (,) this means that there will be an extra comma at the end which is not valid is some browsers.

Invalid Example

```
var myObjArr = [
  {
    contentEl: 'tab'+'123', 
    title: 'name123',
    closable: false,
    autoScroll: true
  },
  {
    contentEl: 'tab'+'456', 
    title: 'name456',
    closable: false,
    autoScroll: true
  },
];
```

Valid Example

```
var myObjArr = [
  {
    contentEl: 'tab'+'123', 
    title: 'name123',
    closable: false,
    autoScroll: true
  },
  {
    contentEl: 'tab'+'456', 
    title: 'name456',
    closable: false,
    autoScroll: true
  }
];
```

Note the second sample has no extra comma (,).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your loop is working you probably don't want to have the same value every time. I think you might want to use i instead of 0. That is just a wild guess though since I really can't tell if the loop should work or not.

```
contentEl: 'tab'+'<%= dataTable.Rows(i)("TabID").ToString()%>',
```